# How to open folder of a file not in the project explorer in Eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-cdt

I know there are various plugins like StartExplorer or Easy Shell that allow to open the containing folder for files or folders that are selected in the project explorer. What I looking for is to open the containing folder for a file that is NOT in the eclipse project explorer.

A typical situation I find myself is in CDT view, I crtl-click on an include statement and open an .h file that is not in the project explorer, so I can't use the plugins above to open the containing folder.  The pathname tip appears for 5 seconds when I put the mouse pointer on top of the name of the file, so I can navigate to that folder manually, but sometimes I get a very very deep pathnames and it takes ages to navigate there, and I have to check the pathname tip many times because it keeps disappearing. Other editors have a open containing folder option when you right click on the name of the file. I miss this functionality in eclipse.

Does anybody know how to solve this?

EDIT: An easy way to reproduce this situation is by dragging and dropping a text file from outside eclipse into eclipse. I'd like to open the containing folder of this file (imagine I didn't know where it came from). As suggested below, I tried Ctrl+Return, but it doesn't work in this situation, it just says there is not property pages for this file.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the file properties (<kbd>Alt+Return</kbd> or via the context menu).

The location field is actually a non-editable text which means you can select the value (<kbd>Alt+L</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+A</kbd><kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd>) and copy it to the clipboard.

If that doesn't work, then try <kbd>F2</kbd>. Some tooltips then become windows so you can copy&paste the content.

If that also doesn't work, then I fear you'll have to file a feature request.

**[EDIT]** Seems like you hit [Bug 207467](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=207467) - [PropertiesDialog] Properties page for external files

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately, if I press Alt+Return in the file that is not in the project explorer I get a window popping up saying "No property pages for stddef.h" (stddef.h is a file I arrived to by crtl-clicking on various include statements). If I try the same Alt+Return for a file that is in the project explorer, then I get a window with the properties for the file, and I can see the Location field which I could copy.  I need a solution for the first case.

Comment: :-/ Does the pathname tip turn into a window that stays on the screen when you press `F2` while the mouse is inside of it?

Comment: No, F2 doesn't do anything with this pathname tip :-(

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I see this problem has been registered as bug before. That was registered in 2007 and the status is still new!!! I guess it's not going to be solved soon enough for me :-(

Comment: Unless you can convince your boss that the problem is important enough to spend money on a fix :-)

Answer (score -1):

To open the file in the system explorer, download the following jar file

https://github.com/downloads/samsonw/OpenExplorer/OpenExplorer_1.2.0.v201101172217.jar

Then past in the folder `...\eclipse\dropins\`
Now restart Eclipse and you will see a new icon in the toobar.

I have test this with "Eclipse Java Neon".

[image]